# Enable and disable input field with select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form, where I would like that the two input fields "CVR number" and "Telephone" is only enabled if the value is "Yes". (Se attached file which is the end result). The form is looking like this now: [Example on my form](https://form.mimsi.dk/stackoverflow.html)

I tried to make something work with the below code, but I am not sure that I am on the correct track? The second input field is not getting active when I use yes.

What do you think?

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onChange="check(this);">
   <option>No</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="company" disabled="disabled" placeholder="CVR number">
  <input type="text" id="company" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Telephone">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function check(elem) {
    document.getElementById('company').disabled = !elem.selectedIndex;
}
```

**Updated HTML code**

```
    <h3>Do you want a company account?</h3>  
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control"  id="mce-COMPANY" name="COMPANY" id="mySelect" onChange="check(this);">
         <option value="Nej">Nej</option>
         <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <input placeholder="CVR nummer" name="EMAIL" class="mail" type="text" id="mce-EMAIL" id="company1" disabled="disabled"></input>
        <span class="icon4"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

      <input placeholder="Telefonnummer" name="EMAIL" class="mail" type="text" id="mce-EMAIL" id="company2" disabled="disabled" ></input>
        <span class="icon4"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

```js
function check(elem) {
    document.getElementById('company').disabled = !elem.selectedIndex;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onChange="check(this);">
   <option>No</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="company" disabled="disabled" placeholder="CVR number">
  <input type="text" id="company" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Telephone">
</form>
```

[image: Disabled]
[image: Enabled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the same ID for both the fields.

Use 2 different Ids and it works..

```js
function check(elem) {
    document.getElementById('company1').disabled = !elem.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById('company2').disabled = !elem.selectedIndex;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onChange="check(this);">
   <option>No</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="company1" disabled="disabled" placeholder="CVR number">
  <input type="text" id="company2" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Telephone">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is working. Now I will try to figure out how to style the forms with bootstrap :-)

Comment: Your'e welcome! If it had solved your problem, can you accept the solution?

Comment: Yes absolutly. I just tried the solution out. It is not working in my form. Can you see something in my code there should be wrong? It should be correct as I see it? [link] https://form.mimsi.dk/stackoverflow.html [/link]

Comment: Yes also with both fields. When I et it in my form it is not working

Comment: So,  on your form, it never worked for one filed also?

Comment: I just updated my question with the code in select there is right now on the webpage. The code is working here: [link] http://form.mimsi.dk/test.html [/link]